# Talend MySQl Database error

Tags: mysql, talend

I am trying to create a new database connection in talend studio and it is showing me this error:

[image: this error]

```
Connection failure. You must change your database settings.
```

I have configured MySQl installer and also I have searched about this error and saw some answers but neither of them were clear, how can I fix this problem.

Comment: are  you able to connect to your database from other tools like mysql workbench or heidisql?

Comment: @garpitmzn It´s working perfectly like that

Comment: What do the `Details >>` say?

Comment: Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
  java.lang.RuntimeException:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'demo'
      at 

org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:195)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1089)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:315)
      at 
      ... 9 more

Comment: i have added external jars too and restarted the talend studio but it didn´t worked

Comment: can you try this - drag and drop tmysqlconnection component in your job and enter parameters required for connection in this component and run the job. Do not use repository metadata connection for now and see if that works..

Comment: @garpitmzn i have tried that and it is showing an error,--Database connection failed--

Answer (score 0):

The exception thrown says that Talend was unable to connect to the database "demo". Try to create a database with the name "demo" with another SQL tool before connecting to it with talend.